# Close open tags in html wordpress <a>

Tags: html, wordpress

html validator is showing this error and i have to fix it but don't know where to start. any one can help?

Error: Start tag a seen but an element of the same type was already open.

From line 1291, column 22; to line 1291, column 24

s="price">

https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.yarafood.nl%2Fproduct-category%2Fconserven%2F

Comment: can you provide us with some more code? The one that is causing this invalidation? It seems as if you are opening an anchor tag in another anchor tag. Just like `<a><a></a></a>`

Comment: Please check the link

Answer (score 0):

Opening one anchor tag in another is invalid and not allowed.

On line 1206, you have opened an anchor tag:

`<a href="https://www.yarafood.nl/product/druivenbladeren-al-hokool-al-khadraa-groot-2-8kg-x-4st/" class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link woocommerce-loop-product__link">
<img width="300" height="400" src="https://www.yarafood.nl/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/wconn-24575-300x400.jpg" class="attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail size-woocommerce_thumbnail" alt="Druivenbladeren AL HOKOOL AL KHADRAA groot 2.8kg x 4st" srcset="https://www.yarafood.nl/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/wconn-24575-300x400.jpg 300w, https://www.yarafood.nl/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/wconn-24575-225x300.jpg 225w, https://www.yarafood.nl/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/wconn-24575-200x267.jpg 200w, https://www.yarafood.nl/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/wconn-24575-400x533.jpg 400w, https://www.yarafood.nl/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/wconn-24575.jpg 600w" sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px" />
<h2 class="woocommerce-loop-product__title">Druivenbladeren AL HOKOOL AL KHADRAA groot 2.8kg x 4st</h2>`

And on line 1207, you are opening another anchor tag `<span class="price"><a></a></span>`

You have not closed the anchor tag opened on line 1206 before opening another one on line 1207. This is causing the error in validation.

Comment: Thanks. i understand but where and how to fix it?

Comment: you can edit `<span class="price"><a></a></span>` to `<span class="price"></span></a>` if you're not using the empty `<a></a>` for anything

Comment: Got it. but where?

Comment: on the line 1210

Comment: Can you please specify where in wordpress?

Comment: you can go to appearance -> editor and then select this page from the right and then edit the source code on line 1210

Comment: This issue is on too many pages. how can i apply it everywhere?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199073/discussion-between-akhilesh-sharma-and-watcher-sk).